# Filtering Flyway migrations

Tags: java, flyway

I am using Flyway core 8.0.5 and I am configuring it like this:

```
 FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration = Flyway.configure()
                .dataSource(getDataSource())
                .locations(Optional.ofNullable(scriptsMap.get(getDbVendor())).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Unrecognized case: " + getDbVendor())))
                .encoding("UTF-8");
```

And now I want to have two modes - execute all scripts from given locations - that is ready above, and the second mode would be same but I want to filter Flyway migrations and execute only those that has DDL in script name, for example script_1_DDL.sql

Is it possible and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case this should work:

```
Flyway.configure()
    .sqlMigrationSuffixes("DDL.sql")
    .load()
```

References: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/sqlMigrationSuffixes and https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration.html#sqlMigrationSuffixes(java.lang.String...)